# How to print memory referenced by a complex addressing mode, using GDB?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, att, addressing-mode

I am new to assembly and I am trying to print a value stored in the following address.

```
 cmp    %esi,0x10(%rsp,%rax,4)
```

I think it is something like

```
 x/d $rsp+ 0x10 + 4*$rax
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To be sure, specify data size or else gdb will default to the one previously used which might not be dword.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question.  To print a register, use `p /x $rax`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to print the contents of a memory location.

```
x/d $rsp+ 0x10 + 4*$rax
```