# Assembly x86 Programming Debugging (GDB): How to print out data through advancing indexing

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb, embedded

I am wondering how do I print out data through advanced indexing in GDB? For example, say I want to print out the value at 8(%ebp) to get the first parameter passed into a function. How would I do that? The following command does not seem to work:

```
p (int)8 ($esp)
```

I always get this segmentation fault error:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00000008 in ??
> () The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called
> from GDB. GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received. To
> change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on". Evaluation of the
> expression containing the function (at 0x0x8) will be abandoned. When
> the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.

Comment: You need to turn the assembler syntax into a gdb expression. Also, you need to examine memory. Something like `x $esp+8`. Add format specifiers as appropriate.

Comment: Related: [How to print memory referenced by a complex addressing mode, using GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52998800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `8($esp)` tries to call `8` as a function, with `%esp` as the arg.  (But absolute address `8` is not in a valid executable page).  Remember that GDB uses GDB's C-like syntax, not AT&T assembly addressing-mode syntax.

Register + offset is hardly "advanced indexing", but regardless, it's easy enough to translate to a GDB expression:

```
x  $esp + 8
```

The `x` command examines memory at that address.  Use `help x` to see options for formatting and how many elements to display.  `p` would print the address, unless you cast it to a pointer and dereference it like `p *(int*)(8 + $esp)`